# External component has thrown an exception at microsoft sql server Dts runtime

Tags: ssis, sql-server-data-tools

ERROR MESSAGE :

> external component has thrown an exception at microsoft sql server Dts runtime dtsContainer execute(Connections connections,Variables variables, 
>   IDTSEvents100 events, IDTSLogging100log, Object transaction)
>
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DtsContainer.Execute(Connections connections, Variables variables, IDTSEvents events, 
>   IDTSLogging log, Object transaction)
>   at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Server.ISServerExec.ISServerExecutionEvents.StartPackage()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Server.ISServerExec.ProjectOperator.PerformOperation()

I have created an new SSIS package, where it exports the data from ODBC Source (Postgresql view) to excel destination. The package was working fine in production till 1 week and finally it stopped and throwing the below error. Package is failing from both the SSIS DB and SQL Agent job.

ODBC Source query -

```
Select col1, col2, coln from viewname
```

SSDT version is -2017 and Target sever version is -2016.
And i have taken care of 32 bit mode.
Run64bitRunTime is set to false.
Tried recreating the package from scratch with new dataflow components and connection managers.

NOTE: The same package works fine on Development box from both SSIS DB and Sql Agent Job without any issues.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I suspect it has something to do with the excel task. Excel task only runs on 32-bit. Try running it in 32-bit and see how it goes.

In Agent job, try ticking the '32-bit runtime' under Configuration > Advanced
[job step configuration window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebE7m.png).
In visual studio, right click the project and under debugging, choose 'False' for Run64bitruntime.
[project properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npaxj.png)